# nginx missing sites-available directory

Tags: nginx, centos, virtualhost

I installed Nginx on Centos 6 and I am trying to set up virtual hosts. The problem I am having is that I can't seem to find the `/etc/nginx/sites-available` directory.

Is there something I need to do in order to create it? I know Nginx is up and running because I can browse to it.

Comment: If you want to split one large config file into smaller ones, you can use my script to split it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38635284/1069083

Answer (score 485, accepted):

Well, I think nginx by itself doesn't have that in its setup, because the Ubuntu-maintained package does it as a convention to imitate Debian's apache setup.  You could create it yourself if you wanted to emulate the same setup.

Create `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and then edit the `http` block inside `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and add this line

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

Of course, all the files will be inside `sites-available`, and you'd create a symlink for them inside `sites-enabled` for those you want enabled.

Comment: RedHat relatives (i.e. Fedora and Centos) don't have this feature out of the box like Debian/Ubuntu. It's easy to copy, as @Mohammad said, however not having nice defaults is confusing for newcomers.

Comment: God, I can't say how many searches I did to figure this out. I am using Amazon Linux AMI release 2014.03. These directories are not created automatically if you install nginx from the rpm files(whether nginx 1.6.2 or nginx 1.7.5) but many nginx configuration examples refer these...making you wonder whether your nginx got installed correctly or not.

Comment: I tried this on my Amazon Linux AMI, but it is not working. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: @JiayiZhou not at all, just reload nginx, if it's not working then explain what you did so I could help you.

Comment: I followed (https://www.sitepoint.com/deploy-your-rails-app-to-aws/) to deploy my ruby on rails app to the server. I did it sucessfully if my server uses ubuntu. But I need to deploy the app to a server using Amazon Linux AMI. I thought it should be the same. So I did exactly the same steps untill the config of nginx. In Amazon Linux AMI, there is no folder sites-enabled and sites-available. So I  created these two folder. Put the config file in sites-available, create the symlink in sites-enabled, add include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*; in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf. But not working...

Comment: shouldn't it be ```*.conf``` ? Also is this how you synlink a new conf file? ```sudo ln -s sites-available/test.conf sites-enabled/test.conf```

Comment: @zeros-and-ones I guess you could say that, even though I don't consider this a wrong and right kind of thing, just a preference.

Comment: Cool thanks, how about the symlink? Is my syntax correct? It doesn't seem to be getting  found by the include statement.

Comment: when i run ```ls -l``` I get this: test.conf -> sites-available/test.conf so it looks correct, but the user shows root not the user that own the original test.conf

Comment: @zeros-and-ones just to make sure before we investigate, did you reload nginx?

Comment: yes restarted it after each change. i'll try again.

Comment: I fixed it, started fresh and created sym link like this: ```sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/test.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test.conf``` not sure why the full path made a difference :/

Comment: What we are missing now are scripts to enable/disable websites with autocompletion ^^ (Like `a2ensite` and `a2dissite` for Apache)

Comment: Hey I believe I followed all the steps correctly, but it doesn't seem to reroute from port 80 to 3000. here's an SO question I posted, detailing exactly what I did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978535/cant-get-nginx-to-reroute-from-test-page-on-port-80-to-3000-using-linux-ami

Comment: does the server_name variable matter in the test.conf? inside sites-available/ ?

Comment: Thank you so much. Built nginx from source and didn't realize ubuntu did this.

Comment: This can cause `default_server` problems if you are switching between different nginx images. Basically if you have a `default_server` setup in your nginx config remember to remove the default config in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` if installing from a debian based image.

Comment: To avoid editing the default configuration file, I opt for creating a new file at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/sites-enabled-includes.conf` and put your `include` directive in there. (The *conf.d* directory exists by default in CentOS 7, nginx/1.12.2)

Comment: I'm used to having the folders *sites-available* and *sites-enabled* present but since moving from Mint to Manjaro I had to do this manually. Simply create the folders, cut the existing default server block from */etc/nginx/nginx.conf* and paste it into the default file **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**. Customize this as needed. Once done, make a sym link in the *sites-enabled* folder then test if everything is ok: `sudo nginx -t`. If there were no problems then restart nginx: `sudo systemctl restart nginx`.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady , I'm running `nginx` via docker container. How do I correct it in this case? Thank you

Comment: @GitHunter0 Probably you can mount the config as a volume, what do mount when you run the nginx container ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady, in docker-compose I just link the nginx.conf file but I will have to inspect the Dockerfile that generated nginx container for other information

Answer (score 86):

If you'd prefer a more direct approach, one that does NOT mess with symlinking between `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`, do the following:

1. Locate your nginx.conf file. Likely at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
2. Find the http block.
3. Somewhere in the http block, write `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` This tells nginx to pull in any files in the `conf.d` directory that end in `.conf`. (I know: it's weird that a directory can have a `.` in it.)
4. Create the `conf.d` directory if it doesn't already exist (per the path in step 3). Be sure to give it the right permissions/ownership. Likely root or www-data.
5. Move or copy your separate config files (just like you have in `/etc/nginx/sites-available`) into the directory `conf.d`.
6. Reload or restart nginx.
7. Eat an ice cream cone.

Any `.conf` files that you put into the `conf.d` directory from here on out will become active as long as you reload/restart nginx after.

Note: You can use the `conf.d` and `sites-enabled` + `sites-available` method concurrently if you wish. I like to test on my dev box using `conf.d`. Feels faster than symlinking and unsymlinking.

Comment: The point of the symlinking "mess" is that you can preserve config files and still disable virtual hosts very easily. If you use your approach, you have to move the files out of conf.d when you want to disable a site which I don't think is any less messy than conveniently deleting a symlink.

Comment: @bviktor I hear ya. I actually use both ways. I just found it more tedious [when testing configs] to bounce back and forth between the sites-available and sites-enabled dirs. In my production env I'm planning on using symlinking.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, typing ln -s `../sites-available/...` is rather tedious when quickly testing stuff, but in the long run it's handy and easier to manage :)

Comment: @bviktor So thankful for the ability to be able to hit tab in terminal when writing a path name and watch auto-complete do it's thing. Didn't know about that for a while until I watched a video with someone using it. I thought they typed at 300 wpm! Then I caught on. :)

Comment: @bvktor Only sites with .conf extension are getting included. If you don't want a site to be enabled, just add .disabled extension to the site configuratoin file. That's the standard convention in CentOS / Apache and it will apply to Nginx as well.

Comment: a little surprised no one has suggested to `include /etc/ngins/conf.d/*.enabled` or something similar, disabling a virtual host would require just to rename the _.enabled_ away from the name

Comment: @Purefan @all Can config files end with anything or do they have to end with `.conf`. I couldn't find anything in the documentation or man page. Can someone find the definition which files are considered?

Comment: @xuiqzy The docs do mention `nginx.conf` specifically but I think its not a hard requirement that all config files have extension `.conf`, still I think its encouraged and helps quickly identify its a configuration file

Answer (score -5):

I tried sudo apt install nginx-full.
You will get all the required packages.

Comment: CentOS uses YUM package.