# Setting up site with homebrewed nginx got 404 on site? Reason why it is happening?

Tags: php, nginx, config, homebrew

I found many links regarding this type of topic , so far i still could not solve my problem.
I have just installed nginx via homebrew. Here are the steps that i did :

1. Added site name to etc/hosts

   ```
   127.0.0.1 mysite.com
   ```
2. On my usr/local/etc/nginx, i created folder using

   ```
   mkdir sites
   ```

   (most instructions i have read so far already have sites-enabled or sites-default on thier setup, but mine was clean so i created one.) Then within the folder i created file just using vim :

   ```
   vim mysite
   ```

   then in the file i have this :

   ```
   server {
     listen 80;
     server_name mysite.com;

     root /Users/myname/mysite/mainsite;

     client_max_body_size 10M;

     # serve static files
     location ~ ^/(images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/  {
       expires 30d;
     }

     location / {
       index  index.php index.html index.htm;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
     }

     error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
     location = /50x.html {
        root   /opt/local/share/nginx/html;
     }

     location ~ \\.php$ {
       fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_index index.php;

       fastcgi_param FF_BOOTSTRAP_ENVIRONMENT dev;
       fastcgi_param FF_BOOTSTRAP_CONFIG webroot/dev;

       fastcgi_buffer_size 1024k;
       fastcgi_buffers 1024 1024k;
       fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 1024k;

       include /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
     }
   }
   ```

After this i include my created folder to nginx.conf and nginx.cnf.default but after this i still get a 404 error. The above configuration on mysite file, except for some directory changes, worked on my other computer but some how i cant replicate for it to work, I tried revising and editing my directory in root but i still get 404. Did I miss some important stuff when configuring? Or what are the other possible reasons why i cannot access mysite.com after the above configuration or how i would get 404. Also i think no other background applications are currently running because i have just restarted the computer to see it the site doesnt work.. Any more suggestions why this might be happening? Thanks in advance

404 :(

Comment: what URL are you trying to request?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady i was typing in my browser mysite.com, it ought to be getting my index that i declared on root on my nginx file. But instead it gives me 404

Comment: if you `ls /Users/myname/mysite/mainsite` do you find the `index.php` ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady uh, from what directory does root fered to if i test ls? actually, i have used tis project from another computer and it works just fine, im trying to set it up in a another one. i just copied the setup and changed some naming on the directory..

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady i have just used ls on my very root directory, and yes i can find an index.php

Comment: Ok I just re-read the question, I found out that I missed a part in it, I'll explain every thing in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you mentioned the missing sites-enabled part, probably cause you're using centos or some other distro, I've explained this part on [my answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413526/nginx-missing-sites-available-directory/17415606#17415606)

Your site isn't working because nginx can't see the config file, simply creating a folder in anywhere doesn't work, you need to tell nginx to look into you config file, if you're configuration is in `usr/local/etc/nginx` like you said, then you need to move this config file `mysite` to `usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d` at least,

or create the `sites-available`, `sites-enabled` pair like I explained in my other answer and move `mysite` to `sites-available` then symlink to it inside `sites-enabled`

Of course make sure you point things to the right path since your nginx lives inside `usr/local/etc/nginx` instead of `/etc/nginx`

Comment: Yes. I actually saw your answer (on the link you posted above) before i even posted this question. I created the folder 'sites' inside usr/local/etc/nginx and followed your instruction on the other question by including the `sites` folder inside nginx.conf file. But it ddnt work i still get 404. Oh, and i installed nginx via homebrew.

Comment: So you wrote `include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites/*;` ?

Comment: Yes. i wrote that. I actually tried commenting that `include` part out and restarted nginx then tried to acccess the site on browser, it tries to connect me to the internet instead, like 'did you mean mysite. something something', so i thought that nginx really did find the configs on the `sites` folder so i get 404 again. I just cant seem to find out what else i may have missed or error on my 'mysite' file. But then, that 'mysite' file is a copy of a working config from another computer with very similar setting as to this one.