# Include Virtual Host files in Nginx

Tags: nginx, centos

Previously, I had Nginx installed through yum on my CentOS 6 machine. This gave me `/etc/nginx/conf.d` folder, in which I created a separate file per site containing `server` directive and other configuration.

Now, I have to add Phusion Passenger support to Nginx, and uninstalled the one from the main repositories and manually compiled it to `/opt/nginx`. This time it gives `nginx.conf` file, to add my `server` definition blocks.

Is there any way to tell Nginx to load vhost files from a folder, say `/opt/nginx/conf.d`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this line to include configuration files from the /opt/nginx/conf.d folder:

`include /opt/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;`

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what's written in the `nginx.conf`, read what kind of folder it includes inside the `http` block and you'll know where you should put your config files.

In [my answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413526/nginx-missing-sites-available-directory/17415606) I explained how to create the `sites-enabled` and `sites-available` folders, you can replace and/or add more to that include line, using any folder you want, and nginx will read it when reloading the config.