# Nginx proxy config problems for Node.js app

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy

I'm almost certain this is just my ignorance and expecting this to be an easy fix, but basically mydomain.com:3000 serves the correct content, but mydomain.com does not. Here is what my nginx.conf.default file has:

```
upstream mydomain {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 8;
}

server {
    listen       0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name  mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://mydomain/;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

I've been following this article, but can't figure out where my error is:
http://dailyjs.com/2010/03/15/hosting-nodejs-apps/

(Note: I believe my installation of nginx differs from this as there is no sites-available folder. Instead, I'm editing the nginx.conf.default file because I saw the lines for the localhost server above the ones I've got here.)

Basically, **what I want is to be able to visit mydomain.com to load the content, instead of mydomain.com:3000**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all a matter of distros and packages not nginx versions, [I've explained this in a different answer before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17415606/2149092), the main and the only file that matters is `nginx.conf`, if you check that file you would know what folders matters and what don't, for example debian distros add this line in their config

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

So that auto includes all the files inside the `sites-enabled` folder,
Redhat distros use this line only

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

*which is btw still also included in the debian distributed config*,
This means that only the files inside `/etc/nginx/conf.d` are considered, and also they have to end with `.conf`

Just check your `nginx.conf` and make sure that your config is in an included folder, as for the config it self it seems that it should be working fine.

Comment: Thanks - that's actually how I figured out the vhosts folder, with it's files, was where I needed to make my edits.

Answer (score 0):

With the newer installation of NginX, there is a subfolder called vhosts. Virtual Host config data needs to go in this folder. If you add a domain to cPanel using the UI, it creates a vhost file automatically.