# Setting up nginx and unicorn to host my rails static webpage on EC2 linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

so im actually following this tutorial online to help me do the setup.. 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-rails-apps-using-unicorn-and-nginx-on-centos-6-5

Im using AWS EC2 and am using a linux ami.

I manage to guess and find where is my nginx folder is, which is somehow located at usr/local/nginx ? instead of wherever it told me it was. Also i couldnt find the default.conf file, just the nginx.conf and nginx.conf.default file . so i ended up just editing nginx.conf .

Anyways have tested this before, and it works whenever i go to 
http://[Your droplet's IP addr]/tasks

however, it is unable to show me my root site , it kept on showing me the Welcome to nginx! page instead.

Which then leads me to this question.
[nginx missing sites-available directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413526/nginx-missing-sites-available-directory)

And i got lost half way when it asked 
1) to insert the include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
2) and that he meant all the files will be inside site-enabled? what does he meant by all files ?
3) create a symlink ? whats that ??

Hope someone can help me out here :/