# Can't get nginx to reroute from test page, on port 80 to 3000 using Linux AMI

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, nginx

I believe I set everything up correctly. I installed nginx on linux AMI, and the landing page that says "welcome to nginx on linux ami" is displaying correctly.

1) I created `/etc/nginx/sites-available` as well as `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

2) I added a file I named `test.conf` which contained:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name test;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  Host       $http_host;
    proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  }
}
```

3) I added a symlink with the following command:

`sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/test.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test.conf`

4) inside the HTTP block of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, I added:

`include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`

5) restarted nginx

if I go to myURL:3000 I can see what I want to see, but myURL:80 does not reroute to 3000, and stays on the nginx landing page :(. the symlink looks good. Maybe it's a problem of where I put the line in step 4?

Comment: does the server_name matter?

Comment: yes, you need to use the same server name as the one you use in a browser, otherwise it will match your default server.
If ur actual url is for example http://myurl.com then use `myurl.com` as `server_name`

Comment: so I tried the same server name, and it did not work :(

Comment: did you try to check the nginx logs ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady yes no errors :/

Comment: try adding this `error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;`and restart nginx