# Restart nginx: unknown directive "listen"

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I've seen that there are already posts on this subject but despite the attempts I still can't do it.

I want to launch nginx via an AWS ec2. When downloading nginx I didn't have the sites-enabled and sites-workable folders, so I followed the instructions here ([nginx missing sites-available directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413526/nginx-missing-sites-available-directory)) by creating the files and adding the include line in the http of nginx.config. I also created the symbolique link.

But without success... I have the following error when i restart the server with sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart

"Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "listen:" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/react-flask-app.conf:2"

This is my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/react-flask-app.con file:

```
server {
       listen: 80;
       root /home/ec2-user/cecs470-web-app-project-team2/test/testest/build;
       index index.html;

       location: / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }
}
```

And this is my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file.

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    index   index.html index.htm;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
        #
        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        # It is *strongly* recommended to generate unique DH parameters
#        # Generate them with: openssl dhparam -out /etc/pki/nginx/dhparams.pem 2048
#        #ssl_dhparam "/etc/pki/nginx/dhparams.pem";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:SEED:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!RSAPSK:!aDH:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:!SRP;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

Do you have any leads? Thank you

Comment: The directive should be `listen` and `location`, and **not** `listen:` and `location:`.

Comment: See the answer below

Comment: Oh thank you !! Now i have another issue, My site doesn't load, I still have the default site, you know why? i stop and start nginx

Comment: Can u post the new error as update since this one is resolved and choose an answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The listen directive from the following file

```
my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/react-flask-app.con
```

Should be

```
 listen 80;
```

Yours has `:`